# How to divide an integer by double?

Tags: java

Should be `213,3333333...`, but is `320.0`. why?

```
int integ = 320;
System.out.println((double) integ / (double) (3/2));
```

I mean: I'm using double, why do I get integer?

Comment: You shouldn't cast the result of an operation to a double. Instead force all the operands to be doubles. (3/2) should be (3.0/2.0)

Comment: Weird that someone with 11.7k reputation is asking this question.

Comment: `3/2` is `1`. `(double) (3/2)` is `(double) 1`, which is `1.0`. If you want `1.5`, use `1.5`, or `3.0/2`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`3/2` is int division, which results in `1` (and casting it do double results in `1.0`). Therefore you are dividing 320 by `1.0`.

Use `1.5` instead (or `3.0/2` if you must).

Comment: @Aimnox Rather `3d`, as we are using doubles. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the casting to `double` after the division, which is executed with integer arithmetic. The easiest way to force floating point arithmetic is by making one of the operands a double:

```
int integ = 320;
System.out.println((double) integ /(3.0/2));
```

or if the input values are variables:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 2;
System.out.println((double) integ /(1.0*x)/y);
```